# how to make async/await work properly in node js?

Tags: node.js

i am new to node js coding i have two functions in my code one of them,i have made async using async keyword but the issue is it doesn't work the output from second function comes before the first function but i want the output of first function before the second function below given is my code

```
var request = require("request").defaults({jar: true});

var cookieJar = request.jar();

var options = { method: 'POST',
url: 'http://69.30.210.130:8082/api/session',
headers:
    { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
form: { email: 'admin', password: 'admin' } };

request(options, async function (error, response, body) {
if (error) throw new Error(error);

let bod=await body;
console.log(bod)
});

var options = { method: 'GET',
url: 'http://69.30.210.130:8082/api/devices',
qs: { id: '1' },
headers:
{ 'postman-token': '021a3566-e1ea-4dd4-4ceb-c81ecd25ddd1',
 'cache-control': 'no-cache' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
if (error) throw new Error(error);

console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Comment: ok sir i'll definitely take care of that from now onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` uses callbacks as default, it means when you want to chain multiple request, you have to do in this manner:

```
// first request
request({...}, function(error, response, body1) {
    if (error) return console.error('Error', error.message);

    // second request
    request({...}, function(error, response, body2) {
        if (error) return console.error('Error', error.message); 

        console.log(body1, body2);
    });
});
```

`async/await` is meant to simplify working with promises, so you can use [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise):

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

(async function() { // await can be called only from within an async func
    try {
        const body1 = await rp({...}); // first request
        const body2 = await rp({...}); // second request

        console.log(body1, body2);

    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error', e.message);
    }
})();
```

Here, the `body2` will be resolved after `body1` has been resolved. This means `async/await` brings a synchronous behavior into the asynchronous processing.

You can use [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) which is Promises-base out of the box.

---

**EDIT:** `async` from callbacks removed, `axios` reference added

Comment: In the first example, the callbacks don't need to be `async`